# How do you check version of clang-tidy in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, clang

I know that there is a flag to use clang-tidy with CMake:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html

Is there a way that I can check the version of clang-tidy? I am thinking something along the line of `CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION` or `CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION`, but includes the information for clang-tidy when integrating the work flow.

If not, what are my options to hack around it?

Comment: "Is there a way that I can check the version of clang-tidy?" - As far as I understand, CMake doesn't set variable `CMAKE_<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY` by itself, so it doesn't check whether `clang-tidy` ever exists. You could run something like `clang-tidy --version` via `execute_process` command, and extract version number by parsing output of that command. This is how CMake and its modules behave when they need to determine version of some tool and perform actions, specific for a version.

Comment: _Why_ do you feel the need to do this? Your build shouldn't care which version of clang-tidy is injected into it from the outside.